# Sum of integrals converge or not!

Tags: measure-theory

I have an old exam problems I'm trying to solve
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \int_{-R}^0 \frac{x^k}{k!}dx$$

When $R  <\infty$ it seems like dominated konvergence and then change the order of the integral? But what if $R = \infty$? Is the function divergent? I don't find anyway of using dominated convergence.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\int_{-R}^0\frac{x^k}{k!}dx=\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\Bigg|_{-R}^0=(-1)^k\frac{R^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$
hence

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{-R}^0\frac{x^k}{k!}dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{R^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}=-\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-R)^{k}}{k!}=-e^{-R}+1-R$$

Comment: Nice! thanks, can I use dc in the finite case?

Comment: You don't need DCT. You're welcome.@Johan